# downing a rw_semaphore with a read or write lock

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, semaphore

My code has an `rw_sempaphore` that gets unlocked by a single call to my function `unlock()`.  However, when my code is called, it does not know if it currently has a read or write lock.  So it does not know if it should call `up_write()` or `up_read()`.

Can I call both one after the other without any negative side effects? Is there a way to tell if the current thread has a read or write lock?

I tried to call `downgrade_write()` and then `up_read()` but this does not seem to be working either.  Is downgrading a read lock bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up storing the PID of the process that used `down_write()`.  The `unlock()` function checks to see if the PIDs match and does `up_write()` if they do. Otherwise, it does `up_read()`.

Not the prettiest, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I call both one after the other without any negative side effects?

Certainly not! Imagine this:

```
thread A                    thread B:

down_write
                            down_read (blocked)
...
unlock
|\ up_write
|                           (released, acquired read lock)
| ...
 \ up_read (lock messed up)
```

I have never used `rw_semaphore`, but if it's a single-writer-multi-reader lock, then this is your solution.

**Edit: Note that this requires the lock to be recursive. In case of `rw_semaphore` it turns out that it is indeed *not* recursive.**

The problem is easy to solve if we can detect whether the lock is locked in read or write mode (assuming you already know it *is* locked in one of those modes, i.e. it's not unlocked).

Since the lock is multi-reader, then we can use a read-try-lock to know the situation:

```
if (down_read_trylock(sem))
    /* semaphore was locked in read mode */
else
    /* semaphore was locked in write mode */
```

In the `if` case, the semaphore was already locked in read mode, and we locked it again, so it needs **two** `up_read`s. In the else case, the semaphore was locked in write mode so we need one `up_write`. This assumes that `down_read_trylock` doesn't fail due to maximum number of read-locks reached or any other reason except the lock being locked in write mode.

So in conclusion:

```
void unlock(struct rw_semaphore *sem)
{
    if (down_read_trylock(sem))
    {
        up_read(sem);
        up_read(sem);
    }
    else
        up_write(sem);
}
```

Note: test before use!

Comment: this sounds right, but I don't think `rw_semaphore`s can recurse. unless I misunderstand http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rwsem.h#L114 .  can I use the nested functionality, or is there no guaranteeing that it is present

Comment: You're right. It seems like with the `*_nested` functions it may be possible, but I really don't know. A hack would be to check the `count` field of the semaphore. A quick look shows that `count == -1` means write-locked and `count > 0` means read-locked.

Comment: I suppose that would work.  Or I guess I can use a locking mechanism that is recursive in addition to the `rw_semaphore`, although it won't be as pretty.

Comment: @zsalzbank, I remember I had the same problem with normal semaphores. I don't understand why there is no `is_read_locked` and `is_write_locked` function (while there _is_ an `is_locked` function). I doubt this API would change for a long time though, so you're probably ok with using `count`.

Comment: I might try using count, but since that probably isn't its intended use, I used the process PID of the write lock owner as a condition for now.

Comment: @zsalzbank, that's not bad at all. It's not the first time I see an API lacking a functionality and a workaround like that would be needed.